# can someone get the status of an error during try and catch? Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, try-catch, nodes

i am trying to get a status of any error 
is that possible during a try-catch method

example

```
try{
//something to do
}
catch(e){
console.log(e.status)
}
```

I am trying to implement it in the following code

```
try {
      entryModel.entries.push(newEntry);
      return res.status(201).json({
        status: 201,
        message: 'entry successfully created',
        data: {
          newEntry,
        },
      });
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(e.status).json({
        status: e.status,
        error: e.message,
        data: {
          newEntry,
        },
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally, this catch error is about the database and in universal, status_code is **422**  , and the message is **422 unprocessable entity**. but more specific you can pass your error object message :

```
catch (e) {
  return res.status(422).json({
    status: 422,
    error: e.message,
    data: {
      newEntry,
    },
  });
}
```